# what is equivalent of CURL in .NET

Tags: .net

i need to connect to a URL and download data from it. the api documentation state that POST has to be made via CURL but i am using a .NET client.

i wanted to know what is the CURL equivalent in .NET.

tried the following but cannot get it to work

```
 if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null) {
       //     Response.Write(Request.QueryString["code"].ToString());

            string url = "https://company.com/token/";
            string data = "{client_id=id,client_secret=id,grant_type=authorization_code,code" + "="  + Request.QueryString["code"].ToString() + ",redirect_uri" + "=" + "http://localhost:10188/home.aspx" + ",scope=ancestry" + "}";

            WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
            myReq.Method = "POST";
            myReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
            myReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

            UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();

            using (Stream ds = myReq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                ds.Write(enc.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length);
            }

            WebResponse response = null;
            string ret = null;

            try
            {
                response = myReq.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error 400 detected!!");
                }
                response = (WebResponse)ex.Response;
            }
            finally
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    ret = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            Response.Write(ret);
        }
```

the following code is now working

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            reqparm.Add("client_id", mycon.client_id);
            reqparm.Add("client_secret", mycon.client_secret);
            reqparm.Add("grant_type", mycon.grant_type);
            reqparm.Add("code", mycon.code);
            reqparm.Add("redirect_uri", mycon.redirect_uri);
            reqparm.Add("scope", mycon.scope);

            byte[] responsebytes = wc.UploadValues(URL, "POST", reqparm);
            string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(responsebody);
        }
```

Comment: How didn't it work? What error/exception did you get?

Comment: You need to pass valid JSON.  Use JSON.net.

Comment: ok, so i use JSON.NET, no resolution. the error i am getting is {"error_description": "No grant_type provided.", "error": "invalid_request"} where as grant_type has been provided

Comment: `where as grant_type has been provided` The server lies....

Comment: if the server lies then how could get the authorization code?

Comment: json has colons not '=' in it {foo:12} not {Foo=12} also strings must be quoted {fooo:'hello'}. Use json.net and show us the failing code using json.net

Comment: i changed the code to use WebClient class as follows and it works great.

Comment: I think what he meant was, run your json through http://jsonlint.com/